# Generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' attribute

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, vimeo, vimeo-ios

I am trying to add swift library in my objective c project
https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload

I have already added #import “-Swift.h” in my project
to subclass VimeoUpload, I am adding @objc in class definition and it gives me following error

> Generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' attribute because they are not directly visible from Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C doesn't support Swift Generics, that is why you can't add `@objc` directive to your class.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I think you can safely ignore this bot comment, this answer perfectly adequate, IMO